# Java: can I require a child class to define a property value?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, properties, guid

I have an abstract base class that many classes extend.  I'd like all these classes to define a unique value for a specific property that is originally defined in the base class (similar to the `serialVersionUID` property that causes a warning when not defined in classes that inherit from `Serializable`).

Is there a way for me, within my abstract base class, to declare a property that does not have a value, but requires all extended classes to define a value for it?

Note that the value does not have to be associated with each individual instance, i.e.: it can be defined as `static`.

**Edit:** I guess a more basic question I should also ask, since the answers vary so widely, is how does Java implement `serialVersionUID` (in terms of its signature) such that my IDE raises warnings when it's not defined?

Comment: `serialVersionUID` is just an ordinary field that the serialization machinery happens to look for (via introspection). It's presence isn't enforced by the Java language, which is exactly why your IDE issues a warning about it; if the value was really required, it'd be a mandatory error when absent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fields can not be overridden, but methods can. If you need not enforce that the value is constant, use:

```
class abstract Super() {
    /**
     * @return the magic value
     */
    abstract MyType getValue();
}
```

If you do need to enforce that the field is final, you can give each instance its own copy/reference as in the answers of Steve or Mike.

If you can't do that either you can do crazy stuff like:

```
class Super() {
    private static Map<Class<? extends Super, MyType> map = new ...;

    protected Super(MyType value) {
        if (!map.contains(getClass())) {
            map.put(getClass(), value);
        } else {
            assert map.get(getClass(), value) == value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hardly. I'd suggest putting user instructions in your base class' javadoc and checking if property is present before using it: `object.class.getDeclaredField("MY_CONSTANT")`

I think, `Serializable` interface is a good example of such approach.

Comment: Perhaps verifying the presence of the field in the super constructor might be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Reposting to match the criteria I missed:

```
public abstract class Abstract {

    private static int field;

    public Abstract(int aValue) {
        field = aValue;
    }

    public int getField() {
        return field;
    }
}

public class Child extends Abstract {

    private static final int value;

    static {
        value = 10; //Pick a value for each class.
    }

    public Child() {
        super(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is essentially what I'm doing right now, except my `Child()` constructor takes no parameters, calling `super()` with the `aValue` property defined in the call to super itself.  It seems like more of a hack than what I would think are other possibilities, though.

Comment: Also good way. But he says he needs one value per class (not object), so _Child_ constructor doesn't really need parameter.

Comment: Well, you and I came up with the same solution. Call it a hack, but it felt natural to me. :)

Comment: @Mike I think it's perfectly fine :)  The only downside I see is that it requires base superclass instead of just common interface.

Comment: I agree, Nikita. I suppose the real question is, how do we raise compiler warnings by ourselves?

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following is a typical approach to this:

```
public abstract class Superclass {

    private final String something;

    public Superclass(String something) {
        this.something = something;
    }

    public String getSomething() {
        return something;
    }
}

public class Subclass {

    public Subclass() {
        super("a value for something");
    }
}
```

You don't get to have a static property value though.